# CGAC2022 Day 2: Self-trapping Elf

Tags: code-golf, grid

Part of [**Code Golf Advent Calendar 2022**](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25251/announcing-code-golf-advent-calendar-2022-event-challenge-sandbox) event. See the linked meta post for details.

---

An Elf is hopping on a chessboard which extends infinitely in all four directions. They move like a generalized chess Knight: on each step, they move `X` units horizontally and `Y` units vertically, or `Y` units horizontally and `X` units vertically. (`(X,Y) = (1,2)` would give regular Knight's moves.)

The Elf plays the game "Self-trapping Elf". In this game, the Elf starts at position `(0,0)` and hops around. They cannot hop into any cell already hopped on, including the starting cell. The objective is to trap themselves in the fewest number of steps possible.

**Task:** Given the values of `X` and `Y` (`0 < X < Y`), output the sequence of coordinates that the Elf should visit, so that they can trap themselves in exactly **15** moves.

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

Some explanation can be found [in this Puzzling post](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/104038/71652). There are many ways to achieve this: (the worked out examples are for `(X, Y) = (1, 2)`)

- Choose any position (X) one move away from the origin (O). We will step all 8 cells reachable from X and then move into it.

```
. O . A .
G . . . B
. . X . .
F . . . C
. E . D .
```

- For almost any pair of cells out of `OABCDEFG`, there is exactly one way to move from one cell to the other in 2 steps without going through X.

  The following are valid solutions to the problem:

```
. . . . 1 . . . .
. . . . . . . 3 .
. . . 0 . 2 . . .
. . e . . . 4 . .
d . . . f . . . 5
. . c . . . 6 . .
. . . a . 8 . . .
. b . . . . . 7 .
. . . . 9 . . . .

. 0 b 6 .
a 5 . 1 c
. . f . 7
4 9 . d 2
. e 3 8 .
```

The actual output for the first answer would be

```python
[(1, 2), (2, 0), (4, 1), (3, -1), (5, -2), (3, -3), (4, -5), (2, -4),
 (1, -6), (0, -4), (-2, -5), (-1, -3), (-3, -2), (-1, -1), (1, -2)]
```

You may include or exclude the starting position of `(0, 0)`.

Comment: I assume the starting position is only allowed as the 16th element?

Comment: @Neil No, I meant at the start.

Comment: It turns out that I was able to save three bytes using a different approach anyway.

Comment: May I take input as a complex number and output a list of complex numbers?

Comment: @alephalpha Yes, that's fine.

Comment: Related: [The Path Of The Wildebeest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/179157/53748); [Trapped Knight Sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/179195/53748).

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 50 bytes

```
Ｆ²⊞υＮ≔⟦υ⮌υ⟧θ≔⁺θ±θθ≔⁺θＥθＥι⎇μλ±λθＩΦΣＥθ⟦Ｅ§θ⊖κ⁺λ§ιμι⟧κ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVA7CgIxEO09RbCaQCy0EqxEEbZQFrVbtojrqMEkuvmInsVGUNEreRYbE7-NU8ww8-a9N8z-Wiy4KVZcHg5n72a15u0-WxkCDUpSbxfgGUn02ruBVxM0QGmr0rZWzDVkARriBo1F8DRnpPxhqfQWSkYGOOcOoaT0L9zn608RjIzRaG52oBiRX6qkMV7s1AjtoMOtg56QLpwz8greIlmsbZfoKW5j38XCoELtcArLqPA0DcKfneContIijzns0NbJTgr7fsQlq9Y2spof66TxmjwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｆ²⊞υＮ
```

Input `X` and `Y`.

```
≔⟦υ⮌υ⟧θ≔⁺θ±θθ≔⁺θＥθＥι⎇μλ±λθ
```

Generate all of the positions one step away from the origin.

```
ＩΦΣＥθ⟦Ｅ§θ⊖κ⁺λ§ιμι⟧κ
```

Output the positions and in between each pair of positions also output the other position one step away from both.

If string input and complex output is acceptable, then for <s>38</s> 36 bytes:

```
Ｆ+-Ｆ⁴⊞υ×Ｉ⪫⟦θιηj⟧ωＸＩ1jκΦΣＥυ⟦⁺ι§υ⊖κι⟧κ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY7NCoJAFIX3PcVlVndoXBgtAldRBAWBUDtxYTri6Kg1P9m7tEioqFfqbdJsd_jO4eNc33EWqbiOZNs-rUmd2eeW1gqQjB1C4RenFHyrM7QM9qLkGheRNripRYXBiYFgkDEgOQkZNJQy8OuGq2FE3Jx0pKCUeiNficrgSkjT1Ttb4jY69tLAl1Zjp5mbdZXwS8-WPFa85JXhCRa9VIR0EHkPfYj1_-wrIM5ZkvDuwmQgXw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｆ+-Ｆ⁴⊞υ×Ｉ⪫⟦θιηj⟧ωＸＩ1jκ
```

Generate all positions one step away from the origin.

```
ΦΣＥυ⟦⁺ι§υ⊖κι⟧κ
```

Output the positions and in between each pair of positions also output the other position one step away from both.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 79 bytes

Expects `[Y, X]`. The path is hardcoded.

```javascript
V=>[p=[0,0],..."763145621057234"].map(d=>p=p.map((v,k)=>v+V[d&1^k]*~-(d>>k&2)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY/LasMwEEX3/YrBi3gmUYTtxM4iSNBFv6CQjaqC8SNV/JCRjYkh9NdTNbRddHdn5gyHe8nnfCycGaZtb8vqXov7SUg1CBWxSDPOeXDIdvE@zZI4Sg/Jbh9o3uUDlkIOYnhEnFlDQs6bkypX8Xuj159bLKVsVgkR3V01goAaVcIg1nR86vyo9BH8gdfWveTFB6K6Mlg0A0MgJGCnFthAoj36F283eHYuXzAlXpu2xYAHROr6Cxo@2dfJmf6McUZeVNh@tG3FW3tGL/u3Cd/60L92jw7u2@r4xZoeQwiJfqJnfIUv)

Or **[78 bytes](https://tio.run/##XY/LasMwEEX3/YrBi3imUYTt1M4iSNBFv6CQjaqC8SNV/JCRjYkh9NddNbRddHdn5gyHe8nnfCycGaZdb8tqrcV6ElINQkUs0oxzHhyyffyUZkkcpYdkH2je5QOWQg5iuEecWUNCztuTKjfxe6MfP3dYStlsEiJaXTWCgBpVwiDWdHzo/Kj0EfyB19a95MUHoroyWDQDQyAkYKcW2EKiPfoXbzd4di5fMCVem7bFgAdE6voLGj7Z18mZ/oxxRl5U2H60bcVbe0Yv@7cJ3/rQv3b3Du7b6vjFmh5DCIl@omd8hS8)** if we don't output the starting position.

#### Encoding

The directions are encoded with 3-bit values, using the following scheme:

```
 d | as binary | (dx,dy)
---+-----------+---------
 0 |   0 0 0   | (-Y,-X)
 1 |   0 0 1   | (-X,-Y)
 2 |   0 1 0   | (+Y,-X)
 3 |   0 1 1   | (+X,-Y)
 4 |   1 0 0   | (-Y,+X)
 5 |   1 0 1   | (-X,+Y)
 6 |   1 1 0   | (+Y,+X)
 7 |   1 1 1   | (+X,+Y)
       | | |
       | | +--> if set, use X for |dx| and Y for |dy|
       | |      (if cleared, do it the other way around)
       | +----> sign of dx (positive if set)
       +------> sign of dy (positive if set)
```

#### Commented

```javascript
V =>                 // V[] = input vector [ Y, X ]
[ p = [0,0],         // p[] = current position, initialized to [ 0, 0 ]
  ...                //       this is also the 1st direction (zero'ish)
  "763145621057234"  // <-- = the directions for the next 15 moves
]                    //
.map(d =>            // for each direction d:
  p =                //   update the position:
    p.map((v, k) =>  //     for each coordinate v at index k:
      v +            //       add to v
      V[d & 1 ^ k] * //       either V[0] or V[1] according to bit #0
      ~-(d >> k & 2) //       multiplied by either -1 or +1
                     //       according to bit #1 or bit #2
    )                //     end of inner map()
)                    // end of outer map()
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>23</s>  17 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

<sup>-3 by using `ṃ` - I really should know to use this since I actually implemented this atom! >.<

-1 altering valid move generation code.

-2 compressing in a way so as not to need valid move construction.</sup>

```
;N“©Ȯṅ!ı|⁺⁸’ṃs2+\
```

A monadic Link that accepts the pair `[Y, X]` and yields a list of coordinates.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATAAz/9qZWxsef//O07igJzCqciu4bmFIcSxfOKBuuKBuOKAmeG5g3MyK1z///9bMiwgMV0)** Or try it with a [formatted output](https://tio.run/##AU8AsP9qZWxsef//O07igJzCqciu4bmFIcSxfOKBuuKBuOKAmeG5g3MyK1z/w4fCqy9DK8aKxZLhuazigqzDlyJKJFN6MFpv4oCdLkf//1s1LDJd).

#### How?

```
;N“©Ȯṅ!ı|⁺⁸’ṃs2+\ - Link: pair of integers, [Y, X] (1 < X < Y)
 N                - negate -> [-Y, -X]
;                 - concatenate -> [-Y, -X, Y, X]
  “©Ȯṅ!ı|⁺⁸’      - base 250 number = 477042125414097387
            ṃ     - (that) base decompress ([-Y, -X, Y, X])
                    -> convert to base 4 using [-Y, -X, Y, X] as digits [1, 2, 3, 0]
             s2   - split into twos
                \ - cumulative reduce by:
               +  -   addition (vectorises)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 63 bytes

```
t->Vec(((u=conj(s=t/(I-x^2)%y=x^8)+s*y)*x^3-u+t)/(1-x)%y^2+u%x)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMHiNAXbpaUlaboWN-1LdO3CUpM1NDRKbZPz87I0im1L9DU8dSvijDRVK20r4iw0tYu1KjW1KuKMdUu1SzT1NQx1K4BScUbapaoVmhBjNhYUZeaVaKRpGCpoKxhpeWpCxRcsgNAA)

Takes a complex number (`X+Y*I`) and outputs a list of complex numbers.

Implements the algorithm in [@Neil's Charcoal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/255098/9288) using polynomial magics.

```
. . d . 1 . .
. . 0 . c . .
. e . . . 2 b
. . . f . . .
. 6 . . . a 3
. . 8 . 4 . .
7 . 5 . 9 . .
```

---

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 71 bytes

```
t->s=0;[s+=a|a<-[-v=I*t,t,t,v,v,-t,-u=conj(t),-v,w=I*u,u,u,-w,-w,-u,w]]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMHiNAXbpaUlaboWN91LdO2KbQ2so4u1bRNrEm10o3XLbD21SnRAsAwIdUt0dEttk_PzsjRKNHV0y3TKgdKlOiCoWw5GpTrlsbEQ4zYWFGXmlWikaRgqaCsYaXlqakLEFyyA0AA)

Gives the same result as above, but the directions are hardcoded.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python](https://www.python.org) NumPy, 93 bytes (@alephalpha)

```python
lambda p:cumsum(kron([p,-p,*conj([p,-p])],[1,-1,1j,-1j])[-(r_[:14,15]^1)])
from numpy import*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY5NTsMwEEb3OYWXM66NMGpRVckncQ0KJS5x4x9cW4orbsImEoI7cRsa0s3M6Gn0fe_zJ9b8Fvz0ZeT-u2TDt796aN3La0vi7lDcuTg4peBBRcYjo4fg7XJr1EwJxgUT9jqtRsUhPaudWDOx0U8CNTYmBUd8cbGS3sWQMr2VfIzyYbWxTZUGRmxi6n2GyobOQ_H9e-nmqHtWNaKU4pG1wwCqKi706kKFpfREek9uP8SERBbQ-mMHa_wnl5nAyMa72boc29wBXq1wcZimZf8B)

#### [Python](https://www.python.org) NumPy, 96 bytes

```python
lambda p:cumsum(kron([p,q:=p-2*p.real,-q,-p],[1,-1,1j,-1j])[-(r_[:14,15]^1)])
from numpy import*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY5LTsMwGIT3OYWXtvu7wlWLUCSfxBgwJW7j-hUTS3HFTdhEQnAnbkNLupmRPo1m5vMn1fEYw_xlxON3GQ17-H1x2r--aZTaffHvxeNTjgHLBEMrEtvQtM6ddsAGYEmB5MA4cHtRq4hkOD_Llm-B79QTJ4o0JkePQvGpot6nmEd62_mYxGa1s00VBk-kSbkPI67guoBL6IfSXavuoCpChOD3oJ3DskrG1epMuaX0hPqAbhlkYkYL0OHQ4S35J-crwRNM630Mthz02GFyeUWWD_O8-B8)

Uses complex numbers.

This works essentially by hopping from the trapping square to each of the eight reachable squares and back an then swapping moves 2 and 3, 4 and 5, 6 and 7 (1-based) and so on.
Unfortunately not very short.

Comment: `p-2*p.real` -> `conj(p)`.

Comment: @alephalpha Ah, I thought I was stuck on `p.conjugate`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 37 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
{-∘⊃⍨{,⍉↑⍵(2+/⍵)}{∊⍵,¨2⌽⌽+⍵}⍵×0j1*⍳4}
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=q9Z91DHjUVfzo94V1TqPejsftU181LtVw0hbH0hp1lY/6ugCMnQOrTB61LMXiLSBvFogPjzdIMtQ61HvZpNaAA&f=40pTMMwy4kpTMMoyBgA&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog&m=dfn&n=f)

Input a complex number `yJx`.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 20 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
(ì•Ct-V₂‹Sθ•sÅв2ôÅ»+
```

Port of [*@JonathanAllan*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/255122/52210), so make sure to upvote him as well!

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f4/CaRw2LnEt0wx41NT1q2Bl8bgeQX3y49cImo8NbDrce2q39/3@0kY5hLAA) or [try it online pretty-printed](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f4/CaRw2LnEt0wx41NT1q2Bl8bgeQX3y49cImo8NbDrce2q39v/bwjnNbww@3aAMZh1aCOcWHFxzdUZtwbou63qF1ZS6VF/YeXnF0n0@Q3tGFfodXVJ7bcXwuUOz43NpDu/9HG@kYxgIA).

**Explanation:**

```python
(            # Negate the values in the (implicit) input-pair: [-Y,-X]
 ì           # Prepend it in front of the (implicit) input-pair: [-Y,-X,Y,X]
  •Ct-V₂‹Sθ• # Push compressed integer 856559820693157436
   s         # Swap so earlier quadruplet is on top again
    Åв       # Convert 856559820693157436 to custom base [-Y,-X,Y,X],
             # which basically converts it to base 4, and indexes into the quadruplet
             # (unlike Jelly, 05AB1E uses 0-based indexing, so [-Y,-X,Y,X] → [0,1,2,3])
      2ô     # Then split this list into pairs
        Å»   # Cumulative left-reduce it, keeping all intermediate results:
          +  #  Add the values at the same positions in the pair together
             # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `•Ct-V₂‹Sθ•` is `856559820693157436`.